# Why was this question about Play store reviews closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The question is [this one](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/120147/players-unable-to-post-reviews).

The user, although a bit confused about the site structure, wants to asks the following:

> Is it normal to not receive game reviews suddenly in my PlayStore deployment?

Which, in the particular spirit of the question can be understood as:

> Or there's a gotcha in Google Playstore I'm not aware of?

Which is short, scoped, related to game development (actually: publishing), and above everything *asking for facts or references*. It is not a: *was my game so crappy?* or something alike. The OP even asks for the possibility of a weird behavior (*Players unable to ...*).

But above everything, he's asking for experiences and facts (*Is it normal?*).

In fact, if the first comment was more elaborate (the one which starts *Yes, it is normal*), it could be promoted to an answer.

Perhaps the question itself could be seen as bad quality and downvoted, but making a quick assumption as *is asking for opinions* and using a moderator close vote on it instead of leaving the chance of VtC to the community sounds a bit unilateral.

**Edit**: Before god-fingering the question, [remember the *same* Help Center about subjective questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

- inspire answers that explain “why” and “how” (in this case, the user tried to understand his problem).
- tend to have long, not short, answers (not explicitly covered by the user).
- have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone (in this case, the user was not ranting but asking).
- invite sharing experiences over opinions (by asking *it is normal* the user is expecting facts).
- insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references (not explicitly covered by the user).
- are more than just mindless social fun (in fact, he had an actual problem).

From the tone of the answer, it eas easily seen that points 3 to 6 were covered (since the user, although having an attempt of hypotesis, wanted to know how normal is and about facts).

Additionally:

- The user tried to undestand what was happening. Reasons involve a **why**. He wanted to validate his (ill-formed but present) hypotesis.
- The user **never asked for a list of experiences**. Just understand what was going on.

Answer (score 3):

Asking for a list of people's *experiences* is not on topic. From the [help center](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed,
>   avoid asking subjective questions where … every answer is equally
>   valid...

My experience with reviews on the Play store is completely valid and factual. So is Almo's. So is Jon's. So is *everybody's* on this site. That's not the kind of question we consider on-topic.

> Perhaps the question itself could be seen as bad quality and
>   downvoted, but making a quick assumption as is asking for opinions and
>   using a moderator close vote on it instead of leaving the chance of
>   VtC to the community sounds a bit unilateral.

It *is* unilateral. Such is the power granted to the elected site moderators; we were not elected so that we would *not* use the abilities given to us to moderate the site. The community still has the power to both (a) individually overturn the closure by casting reopen votes and (b) set the policy of the site, within a certain degree dictated by StackExchange, alter the policies of the site.

If you'd like to personally propose updating the site policies to allow such questions, you are welcome to craft such a proposal here on meta.

Comment: So you should remove everything about subjective questions in the help center since it **is** misleading. Quoting: *invite sharing experiences over opinions.*, *insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references.*, *are more than just mindless social fun.*, *have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone.*

Comment: [Some subjectivity](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) is fine; certain kinds of it are good, acceptable, and welcomed. But what this question is asking for right now is *just* for people to talk about their experiences, there is no one experience that makes sense as the accepted answer to the question... it's just a discussion, and thus a better fit for a *discussion forum*.

Comment: The "Some subjectivity" that says "It seems simple enough: Fact good ..." for a user asking about how normal an event is?

Comment: The same "Some subjectivity" enumerating the exact 4 points I told in the former comment?

Comment: No, those points do not apply here at all. Generally the way you need to look at on/off topic policies is that we start with what is on-topic. That creates a broad set of possible subject matter. We narrow that down by applying further guidelines about what is *off* topic, so those generally take precedent. Asking for list-of-experience answers overrides, generally, any other on-topicness (so, incidentally, does asking yes-or-no questions).

Comment: He did not ask an explicit list of experiences. He asked about it being normal.

Comment: ...which is defined by what, exactly? Other people's experiences. It's also a yes-or-no question.

Comment: There is no "What are your experiences about low reviews in PlayStore"?

Comment: Other's people experiences, yes. Experiences listing, no. The difference between P and P# in computer science, and the difference between polling and websites like Software Recommendations in this community. He had a specific problem or question. Never asked a list.

Comment: In fact, "Other people's experiences" is one of the accepted points in the same article you gave, which is the one in the help center. Quote from the article: """but the best subjective questions unabashedly and unashamedly prioritize sharing actual experiences over random opinions"""

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't agree, and I feel like we're just talking in circles around the issue now. I stand by my decision, but would certainly welcome proposals from the community for updating our site policies.